# Show incoming message dialog for non-users like Allo

Tags: android, google-allo

`Allo` somehow displays an incoming message dialog even if the user haven't installed the app, with buttons to reply, ignore, or install the app.

I've looked at the device logs, and couldn't find any activity involved with this dialog.
The dialog is not coming from my `SMS` app as well.

Anyone knows how's that possible? 
Are they using internal `Android` features, or is it somehow possible to recreate?

[image: First dialog announcing the incoming message]
[image: Dialog appears after sending a reply]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/app-preview-messaging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a new API called "App Preview Messaging" which is in the preview stage.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/app-preview-messaging

Google has started early access program with some partners.

> we're starting with an early access program with several partners and
>   will expand the program over time. This feature is specifically for
>   messaging apps, so if you're a messaging app developer stay tuned for
>   more information on how to participate in previewing this new feature

http://www.androidauthority.com/google-app-preview-messaging-718083/

> Google calls it App Preview Messaging, and it’s rolling out to Google
>   Play services on Android as of today.

Since this API depends on Google Play services, this won't work on devices that don't have Google play services installed.